# How to delete div inside tbody?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

Actually I had used the `div` in `tbody` for different `dialog box`.That's why I put div in tbody. But I want to know how to delete(remove) associative div when I clicked ? Here I tested with table clicked !

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i < 3;$i++){
?>    
<table id="row_<?= $i ?>">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
        <div>Inder Div(Dialog)</div>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("table").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id')); // display table id
        $(this).find("div").remove();//not working
        $(this).closest("div").remove(); //not working
    });
</script>
```

In my project , I used like above format and open dialog when I click **Action** button like below image ... so need to delete dialog
[image]

Comment: invalid markup.

Comment: Your JS doesn't work as your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `div` as a child of a `tbody`. If you check the div in the DOM inspector you'll see it is actually rendered *outside* the `tbody`, which is why `find('div').remove()` doesn't work. Your first job would be to fix the HTML.

Comment: if you MUST have the div as part of the table - use `<tr id="killme"><td colspan=2><div> ... </div></td></tr>` - then you can just look for `#killme` and delete the row - same effect

Comment: So what should I use for dialog box in each table @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You can use a `div`, just put it before/after the `table`, or in a `td` if you *have* to have it inside the table

Comment: As a hack I suggest giving an ID (relevant to "I") to the div and remove that id on Click.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments answering this question:

The code does not work because the HTML is invalid. Instead of rendering the `div` withing the `tbody`, browsers will move the `div` outside of the table. `.find('div')` will return zero result seeing the div is no longer within the table.

**solution:** Move the `div` to after the `table`, which the browser does anyway. To access this `div` use the [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method from jQuery.

```js
$(function(){
  $('table').click(function(event){
    $(this).next('.dialog').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>row1.col1</td><td>row1.col2</td></tr>
</table>
<div class="dialog">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In major browers like chrome etc. the div element is not rendered inside the table tag so to accomplish simply use:

```
$(this).prev().remove();
```

As the div tag is rendered before the table tag in chrome

It is not good pratice to keep anything else in you table tag except table element

Answer (score -1):

Please try and go through Below Codings

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i < 3;$i++){
?>  
<table id="row_<?= $i ?>">
<tbody>
    <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdf</td><td>sdf</td></tr>
    <div id="div_<?= $i ?>">Inder Div(Dialog)</div>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("table").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); // display table id
    $( "#div_"+ this.id ).remove(); //Call by div id
    //$(this).find("div").remove();//not working
    $(this).closest("div").remove(); //not working
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you changed and how that should answer the question.

Comment: I got that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null`

Comment: add the div id which in inside the table. and call the that id for delete in click function

Comment: then replace Below Coding for delete line. 
$( "#div_"+ this.id ).remove();